# Нужен консольный терминал на c#

Tags: c#, .net

Если вкратце, то нужен такой терминал, где при постоянном выводе информации будет всегда и безопасно доступно поле ввода которое бы обрабатывало новые команды, которые впоследствии могут отдавать свою информацию на вывод.

В общем по сути, постоянный беспрерывный вывод информации в одном потоке (или нескольких), ввод в основном потоке, поле ввода всегда разблокировано.

Ищу информацию в сети, но пока особо ничего найти не могу. Если не найду, придется реализовывать все руками. Вопрос в том, есть ли у кого информация о подобных реализованных терминалах?

Comment: А чем не устраивает решение с простейшим GUI - 2 поля, одно для ввода, другое для вывода? Это ведь гораздо удобнее - там весь функционал типа копировать/вставить уже реализован штатно. При правильном подходе, например, WPF+привязка, у вас это не увеличит трудозатрат на разработку, а может и уменьшит, за счет того, что консольный интерфейс придется неплохо так допиливать.

Comment: @Андрей, да как-то лампово, наверное, поэтому даже не думал о гуишке. В плане вывода простого текста, мне кажется, консоль удобней будет, хотя я с гуи давно дел не имел.

Comment: Зря так считаете, а ламповый черный с белым моношинным текстом можно и в GUI нарисовать. У консольного решения куча проблем, нужно продумать как быть при уходе лога за границу экрана - ведь нижняя строчка должна оставаться на месте, такого консоль не поддерживает, т.е. придется отказаться от части лога, которая не вмещается в экран. Ну и про неудобность редактирования + копировать/вставить в консоли я уже писал.

Comment: реализованных не видел, но руками можно. С копированием выведенного действительно будет проблема, а простой скролинг вывода не проблема вовсе, если не нужны экстремальные скорости. Вывод на консоль довольно медленный. Посмотрите [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/607263/198316) и [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/591559/198316), может что-то будет полезно, ну или окончательно склонит вас в сторону простого GUI

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант с консолью - можно попробовать различные telnet клиенты.
Например [вот этот](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Telnet) или вот [этот](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19071/Quick-tool-A-minimalistic-Telnet-library).

По опыту работы с GUID - telnet всегда удобнее был для быстрой разработки, ибо различные реализации вью (Win form, wpf) еще нужно настраивать.